# building different projects of the same solution in TeamCity

Tags: .net, teamcity

I have a git repository containing a few .NET solutions with some shared projects. I'd like TeamCity to trigger a build per solution whenever the solution changes; the problem I'm having is that whenever anything changes in my root directory, Teamcity tells me there are pending changes in the *other* solutions that weren't affected by the changes made.

Is there a way to do what I'm aiming at?

Answer (score 0):

I recomend separate solution for "shared" projects. Or you can have several configurations of solution where "shared" project is not supposed to build.

Comment: Hmm, the different solutions depend on the shared projects, so we cannot really separate the shared ones to their own solution nor exclude them from building- building them with each solution would ensure code quality...

Comment: If you want build both "shared" and "referencing" projects you can build more solutions. We use this scenario for several years without accidents.

Answer (score 0):

Reads like you are using just one repository reference. If you have different solutions you should either create one repository reference (TC-config) for each or edit the checkout rules for each build project to include only the parts of the repo the solution depends on.